# Keras: Callbacks Requiring Validation Split?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a multi-class classification problem with Keras 2.1.3 and a Tensorflow backend. I have two numpy arrays, `x` and `y` and I'm using `tf.data.Dataset` like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"sequence": x}, y))
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(self.batch_size))
dataset = dataset.repeat()
xt, yt = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Then I make my Keras model (omitted for brevity), compile, and fit:

```
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
model.fit(xt, yt, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=10)
```

This works perfectly well.  But when I add in callbacks, I run into issues.  Specifically, if I do this:

```
callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model_{epoch:04d}_{val_acc:.4f}.h5",
                    monitor='val_acc',
                    verbose=1,
                    save_best_only=True,
                    mode='max'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(os.path.join('.', 'logs')),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, min_delta=0, mode='max')
]
model.fit(xt, yt, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks)
```

I get:

```
KeyError: 'val_acc'
```

Also, if I include `validation_split=0.1` in my `model.fit(...)` call, I'm told:

`ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you cannot use validation_split`.`

What is the normal way to use callbacks and validation splits with `tf.data.Dataset` (tensors)?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using `dataset` in this training call: `model.fit(x, y, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks)`. If you use x and y (numpy) without using TF `dataset`, then `validation_split` should work.

Comment: @GergesDib Sorry, mistyped earlier.  That call should have been `model.fit(xt, yt, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks)`.  Given that, how would I us validation split + callbacks?

Comment: What is `xt` and `yt`? The tensorflow Dataset is defined as `dataset`

Comment: @GergesDib Just updated to clarify.  It's from this line: `xt, yt = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()`

Comment: I think your problem is data type of `xt` and `yt` is not list or array, so it can't to slice.

Comment: @MuhammadRafiulIlmiS Yes, that's my error.  But surely there's a way to use callbacks and a validation split while still using tensors?

Comment: What if you don't convert `x` and `y` to tensor? I mean you just pass `x` and `y` to model.fit

Comment: You probably need to split your data before feeding it to `fit`, and use `validation_data` to feed the val set. Check here for an example how to use it https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets

Comment: If you still wanna use tf.Tensor, you have to split first `x` and `y` to `x_train`, `y_train` and `x_val`, `y_val`. next step just follow link that @GergesDib mention

Comment: @GergesDib Thanks again for the help!  I just did that and followed the code here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets (under "Datasets can also be used for validation").  However, when I call `model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset, validation_steps=3, callbacks=callbacks)`, I get `AttributeError: 'RepeatDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'`.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should use the tensorflow keras API, not keras itself. I will give an answer with another example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tensorflow keras API, you can provide a `Dataset` for training and another for validation.

First some imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
```

define the function which will split the numpy arrays into training/val

```
def split(x, y, val_size=50):
    idx = np.random.choice(x.shape[0], size=val_size, replace=False)
    not_idx = list(set(range(x.shape[0])).difference(set(idx)))

    x_val = x[idx]
    y_val = y[idx]
    x_train = x[not_idx]
    y_train = y[not_idx]
    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val
```

define numpy arrays and the train/val tensorflow `Datasets`

```
x = np.random.randn(150, 9)
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 150)

x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = split(x, y)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=10)))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32).repeat()

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, tf.one_hot(y_val, depth=10)))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(32).repeat()
```

Make the model (notice we are using the tensorflow keras API)

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([Dense(64, input_shape=(9,), activation='relu'),
                                 Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                                 Dense(10, activation='softmax')
                                ])
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=10, 
          steps_per_epoch=int(100/32)+1,
          validation_data=val_dataset,
          validation_steps=2)
```

and the model trains, kind of (output):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                640       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 5,450
Trainable params: 5,450
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 69ms/step - loss: 2.3170 - acc: 0.1328 - val_loss: 2.3877 - val_acc: 0.0712
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2628 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 2.3850 - val_acc: 0.0712
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2169 - acc: 0.2656 - val_loss: 2.3838 - val_acc: 0.0712
Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.1743 - acc: 0.3359 - val_loss: 2.3830 - val_acc: 0.0590
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.1343 - acc: 0.3594 - val_loss: 2.3838 - val_acc: 0.0590
Epoch 6/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.0959 - acc: 0.3516 - val_loss: 2.3858 - val_acc: 0.0590
Epoch 7/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0583 - acc: 0.3750 - val_loss: 2.3887 - val_acc: 0.0590
Epoch 8/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.0223 - acc: 0.4453 - val_loss: 2.3918 - val_acc: 0.0747
Epoch 9/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9870 - acc: 0.4609 - val_loss: 2.3954 - val_acc: 0.1059
Epoch 10/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9523 - acc: 0.4609 - val_loss: 2.3995 - val_acc: 0.1059
```

### Callbacks

Adding callbacks also works,

```
callbacks = [ tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model_{epoch:04d}_{val_acc:.4f}.h5",
                    monitor='val_acc',
                    verbose=1,
                    save_best_only=True,
                    mode='max'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard('./logs'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, min_delta=0, mode='max')
]


model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=int(100/32)+1, validation_data=val_dataset,
          validation_steps=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
4/4
 [==============================] - 0s 59ms/step - loss: 2.3274 - acc: 0.1094 - val_loss: 2.3143 - val_acc: 0.0833

Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.08333, saving model to model_0001_0.0833.h5
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2655 - acc: 0.1094 - val_loss: 2.3204 - val_acc: 0.1389

Epoch 00002: val_acc improved from 0.08333 to 0.13889, saving model to model_0002_0.1389.h5
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.2122 - acc: 0.1250 - val_loss: 2.3289 - val_acc: 0.1111

Epoch 00003: val_acc did not improve from 0.13889
Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.1644 - acc: 0.1953 - val_loss: 2.3388 - val_acc: 0.0556

Epoch 00004: val_acc did not improve from 0.13889
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.1211 - acc: 0.2734 - val_loss: 2.3495 - val_acc: 0.0556

Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve from 0.13889
Epoch 6/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0808 - acc: 0.2969 - val_loss: 2.3616 - val_acc: 0.0556

Epoch 00006: val_acc did not improve from 0.13889
Epoch 7/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.0431 - acc: 0.2969 - val_loss: 2.3749 - val_acc: 0.0712

Epoch 00007: val_acc did not improve from 0.13889
```

Comment: This is extraordinarily helpful!  When you said `Make the model (notice we are using the tensorflow keras API)`, could you elaborate?  I'm using things like `tf.keras.layers.Input` and `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`, etc.  Are you saying I shouldn't?

Comment: You are using it correctly, the tensorflow-keras API is `tf.keras.....`. This is same what I am doing here (but I do shortcuts  with import statements)...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is type of your datasets, where `xt` and `yt` is not a list or array, so it can not to slice or split.

Let assume `x` is array with shape `(1000,2)` fill with random number using numpy and `y` is class with 10 classes.

```
# Define x and y
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2018)
n_cat = 10
x = np.random.rand(1000,2)  # Generate random 2 variables and 1000 rows
y = [np.random.randint(1,n_cat) for i in range(len(x))]     # Make 10 class
```

Then you assemble the model and compile

```
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
```

Create callbacks for checkpoint model

```
callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model_{epoch:04d}_{val_acc:.4f}.h5",
                    monitor='val_acc',
                    verbose=1,
                    save_best_only=True,
                    mode='max'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(os.path.join('.', 'logs')),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, min_delta=0, mode='max')
]
```

fit the model

```
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks, validation_split=0.1)
```

it's works for me.